# How to not let the session expire in Joomla when it closes? (Or last longer)

Tags: php, session, joomla

I have a real estate component installed. It has the option of adding properties to favorites and creates a list, but when I close and open the browser, regardless of how long it has closed, it deletes the list.

Talking to the developer he told me that it is because of the sessions that are deleted. And he could not help me. On his demo site, when he closes and opens again, he does not delete the list of favorites.

Does anyone know how to help me, how to do for joomla does not delete the session when closing the browser?

Thank you!

Comment: I think since this is an essential feature for you, you probably want t to make a plugin or component+plugin that creates a cookie for your users with a longer expiration

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do close sessions if you close them. That's simply because the server identifies the user by a cookie. Session cookies are usually set to live just for the time the browser is open. If you close and reopen a browser those session cookies are gone.

But some browsers do only pretend that you close them. Chrome is a good example. So if I close a Chrome window and reopen another one the session continues. Only if I really kill the whole browser I lose my session.

The solution for your issue is to use time based cookies instead. PHP can do this for you. You can do this with PHP code or by configuration.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: I think since this is an essential feature for you, you probably want t to make a plugin that creates a cookie for your users with a longer expiration and then stores the saved items with the unique cookie ID. But I'd still give it an expiration sometime realistic or your database may get huge depending on your traffic. I would think these lists would be pretty useful data.  Joomla has an API for managing cookies so use that rather than the generic php one.